# References in the first stanza of Amiri Baraka's poem "Somebody Blew Up America"?

Tags: poetry, historical-context, amiri-baraka

In the poem ["Somebody Blew Up America"](https://genius.com/Amiri-baraka-somebody-blew-up-america-annotated) by the African-American poet Amiri Baraka, he references a few people at the end of the first stanza:

> They say it's some terrorist
>
> some barbaric
>
> A Rab
>
> in Afghanistan
>
> it wasn't our American terrorists
>
> it wasn't the Klan
>
> or the Skinheads
>
> or them that blows up nigger churches
>
> or reincarnates us in Death Row
>
> it wasn't Trent Lott
>
> or David Duke, or Giuliani
>
> or Schundler, or Helms retiring

Trent Lott was in favour of segregation and David Duke is seen as a Klansman. So it's easy to see why Amiri Baraka is taking aim at them in his politically charged and polemical poem; but why is he taking aim at Giuliani, Schundler and Helms? I don't see any obvious connection with his politics.

Answer (score 3):

Giuliani pushed the "broken windows theory" of policing, intended to punish people for small infractions. The idea was to make people think of New York as a lawful place rather than one of urban decay, but it was often applied in a racially disparate way. It contributed in part to the US having an outsized prison population, and disproportionate racial representation among prisoners.

Helms was famously racist (despite an illegitimate child with a black woman). He opposed civil rights legislation and frequently used race-baiting rhetoric.

[A book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ItAOKZs4PqIC&pg=PA172&lpg=PA172&dq=Schundler%20racist&source=bl&ots=pitZYulBng&sig=tTEpPSddASrc4ZrDarzg7tyx4p4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw94HG1qHdAhWnrFkKHe4UDX8Q6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=racial%20component&f=false) claims Schundler "increasingly resorted to issues with a strong racial component" while losing a campaign to a Democrat. That book was written in 2002, referring to events in the 90s. While these are not on a par with the more explicit and persistent racism of the national figures in the poem, as a New Jersey figure it would have a more personal meaning. New Jersey is a state with a very strong liberal basis but also some sharp racial divisions, and this insight prefigures the way New Jersey's current Republican governor has supported a party that has increasingly used racist rhetoric.